# POST request not going through?

Tags: api, http, endpoints

I'm still trying to see clearly in some aspects of the API.

I have a custom route

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route('my-project/v1/', '/form/post/', array(
    'methods' => 'POST',
    'callback' => 'post_form',
  ) );
})
```

I have a similar one for GET that works perfectly:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route('my-project/v1/', '/form/get/', array(
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'get_form',
  ) );
})
```

Callback method that returns plain text + "null" (using var_dump, be can use echo):

```
function post_form($data) {
    var_dump($data);
    return;
}
```

Alternative callback test method as it was suggested in an answer to another question):

```
function post_form($data) {
    $data = [ 'foo' => 'bar' ];
    $response = new WP_REST_Response($data, 200);
    $response->set_headers([ 'Cache-Control' => 'must-revalidate, no-cache, no-store, private' ]);
    return $response;
}
```

jQuery call:

```
$(".my-project-form-submit").click(function(){
   var serializedForm = $('#my-project-form').serialize();
    $.post("/wp-json/my-project/v1/form/post/", serializedForm, function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });
});
```

Serialization works well, `$.post` is reached and then nothing happens forever, the `alert` line is never reached.

What am I doing wrong regarding this POST?

It's (I think) not a 404 not found case, I had that but I think it's corrected now.
There is no JavaScript error in Chrome's console.

Comment: Everything you posted works fine for me on WordPress 5.1.1. Sounds like it's time to disable plugins and themes and see if you can reproduce the problem.

Comment: I found the source of the problem, see the answer I posted.
I also edited the question because some information was missing to identified it.

Answer (score 1):

I found that it didn't work because both endpoints used the same route.
I expected defining one for POST and one for GET would  result in different callbacks, but they apparently conflict with each other.

In a first time, I get the request going through simply by change the namespace for the POST.

Maybe there is a way to define different callbacks far a same namespace , I need to check that.

(Now, I have another problem which is that $data input is empty, but I need to check things and maybe make another question for that.)